# Google Maps Engine Portable: Offline Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I recently saw some information on GME Portable. It sounds like this tool allows not just GME API access, but also regular Maps and Earth API access offline?

I've recently developed the first stage of a demo for an academic software project with the Google Maps API. It seems to be working perfectly, but I've recently been informed that it needs to be useable in an always-offline mode. Thus, my goal is now to convert this app into something that can be always-offline, but still has the elegance of google maps.

Is it possible, with GME Portable (which I cannot find a download for...) or the regular Google Maps API to develop an application that does not need to http-request Google for the API every time it loads up?

Comment: Your biggest problem is accessing tiles offline. It's illegal to store tiles of google maps. You should consider openlayers http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/offline-storage.html with open street map

Comment: Okay, this is actually what my boss suggested after cursory google searches suggested that my desired product was still impossible. So, thanks!

Comment: Google Maps Engine Portable allows you take tiles offline. Here is a session on this product from Google I/O 2013: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bv6eVTlfRcM

Comment: I found that last week, but it doesn't seem to be /available/, for download or even purchase.

Comment: @alkis: any idea where in the license agreement its given? One of our customer is adamant about getting offline maps with google

Comment: Actually @SeanMaday was the one that gave the link for portable google maps not me. I'm not familiar with this product.