# How to use offline map in Devextreme mobile application?

Tags: google-maps, mobile, offline, offline-mode, devextreme

I'm developing an application that contains an offline mode. I need to use offline map in this Devextreme mobile application. How do I make it ?

Has the google map in such a feature ?

Comment: Probably this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030166/google-maps-engine-portable-offline-maps-api will be helpful.

Comment: dxMap does not provide this functionality. However, since dxMap is based on Google Maps API, check out the following solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294782/using-google-maps-v3-offline-e-g-with-cache-manifest